# Kubernets in disconnected environment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

i'm seeking advice for a K8s design for my use case. I build a product where our services will be running on our devices, and we ship our device to customers and have them use our on-device services at a remote location (without unstable internet connection). We will have a bunch of micro on-device services, and want to use K8s for all services orchestration and discovery. We only want to expose our service to customer and hide all the implementation detail (customers don't need to know, or care if we use K8S or not). Here are my question/concerns:

1. It's not recommended to run k8s controller and worker on different nodes, however our device is expensive, we don't want to waste few nodes to just run controllers. Will there any potential problem running worker and controller on the same nodes? what is best practice in this case.
2. As we want to hide all the detail from our customers, I don't want customer to manage the k8s cluster or service for us, and want our service and k8s self-managed. K8s help us to maintain number of pods for our service pods. But what is the solution for controller pods/nodes. How to make k8s automatically redistribute/reprovision new controller pods if one down?

Answer (score 2):

Your usecase seems related to edge computing. There are multiple solution of K8s trying to address the challenges of edge computing environment and the main options are [K3s](https://k3s.io/), [MicroK8s](https://microk8s.io/), and [KubeEdge](https://github.com/kubeedge/kubeedge).

Regarding you points:

1. Best practices are to separate master and workers nodes to save the master from traffic peak, resources shortage, etc. and keep the cluster able to recover from unexpected situations.
   Running master and workers on the same nodes is not recommended in production mode becasue:

- if the node with the master becomes overloaded it may cause the overall cluster to be unvailable.
- if worker saturate the reosurces, e.g. disk got fully filled, the kubernetes api becomes unstable and possibily unreachable to access, thus the cluster may become unmanageble.

2. Customers can only use accessing components, e.g. Ingress or Service NodePort, to access the application and then eveything else is hided from them. This is a normal Kubernetes usage so you should not worry about that, assuming the customers cannot access the devices directly because there you can see the processes related to the running containers.
   K8s redistribute automatically new pods if one pod crash or if one node goes down, trying to balancing the cluster usage. K8s also reprovisions the pods if they crash or if their node is not reachable according to the replicas you specify in the configuration files.

Since in case of a configuration with master and worker on the same nodes may happen the cluster to become unvailable, you can have 2 situations in case of a master failure:

- if you have only 1 master node the cluster will be down and you should try to access the disk or snapshot to try to recover the previous Kubernetes configuration in `/etc/kubernetes`
- if you use high-availability (HA) configuration, for ex. with 3 master nodes, the cluster will be still available and you should be able to recover from a single master node down.

The steps to recover from in a HA configuration are:

- `kubectl get componentstatus` to check the unhealthy nodes.
- on each master node, remove the failed ETCD nodes connection
- create a new node that will replace the failed one and configure it to connect to the cluster
- update the kube-apiserver with the ETCD servers list.

Comment: 1. the problem is that our device is really expensive, and controller workload might not utilized all the resources (CPU, RAM, DiSK). Does K8s support a mechanism to limit resource for worker pods so that it will not overload controller?
2. Yes for our service pods will be managed by k8s and automatically redistributed. It's my concern when a control node is down (say i have 3 controller nodes) how do k8s automatically provision a new controller node and join it to the existing 2 up nodes?

Comment: btw, KubeEdge look interesting, but it has control plane running in cloud which already ensure the controller availability. However it probably not a good fit for our use case where we need control plane completely deployed on our device at the edge

Comment: k3s and Micro8s are more of lightweight version of K8s for limited resource hardware. which is not really a concern in this case

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to limit the resource usage on nodes. You can limit resource within a namespace or a pod but not related to specific host of the cluster.
What you can do for your usecase is: 1. create a cluster where you use a cheaper device as master node and then use your devices as worker nodes.; 2. "play" with K8s components, such as zone or node affinity, to schedule the lighter pods on the master/worker node and the heaviest pods on the workers. This 2nd solution is a workaround where you should know well your application and how has been splitted into microservices.

Comment: I updated my answer to reply to your second point about what will happen if a master node fails.

Comment: the workload is completely ours, with some pod policy or admission control i think we can properly distribute pods to master/worker and worker nodes.

Comment: To your points abt "The steps to recover from in a HA configuration are:" i assume that you were thinking it's not stacked ETCD ?

Comment: yes because in a stacked cluster if one node (master or etcd) goes down the redundancy is compromised https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology/